# Preencher spinner com dados do SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, spinners

Tenho uma aplicação com o SQlite, eu faço um select para retornar os valores de um campo e guardo isso em uma variável.
Queria usar esses valores em um spinner, porém não está ficando em lista e sim todos os valores em um item só.

Consulta no Sqlite para trazer todos os registros da coluna Titulo:

```
    Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Credenciais",null);
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    while (c.moveToNext())
    {
        buffer.append(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Titulo")));
    }
    String lista = buffer.toString();
```

Tentei no buffer.append concatenar aspas e virgula para ficar do mesmo modo se eu inserisse as informações manualmente ex: {"teste", "teste2", "teste3"}.... também não funcionou.

Meu spinner está desta forma:

```
    String[] Credenciais = new String[] {lista};

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_conteudo);

    Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spn_lista_conteudo);
    spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


    ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, Credenciais);
    aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spin.setAdapter(aa);
}
```

Quando rodo a aplicação ao invés da drop down ficar

teste

teste2

teste3

está ficando na mesma linha : teste teste2 teste3

Se alguém puder me ajudar...

Answer (score 3):

O método `setAdapter()` recebe um Array que deve conter os itens que o Spinner deve listar. Cada item desse array deve corresponder a uma linha da tabela **Credenciais**.

O que você está a fazer é construir, através de `append()`, uma string com o conteúdo de todas as linhas. O Array é construído(`new String[] {lista};`) apenas com essa string, ficando tudo num único item.

O que deve fazer é construir o Array ao percorrer o Cursor.
Declare um método para esse efeito:

```
public ArrayList<String> getCredenciais(){
    ArrayList<String> credenciais = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Credenciais",null);
    if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            credenciais.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Titulo")));
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return credenciais;
}
```

Use-o assim para criar o Spinner:

```
Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spn_lista_conteudo);
...
...

ArrayList<String> credenciais = getCredenciais();
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, credenciais);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

spin.setAdapter(adapter);
```

<sub>**Nota:** Alterei a forma de percorrer o Cursor para uma que acho mais adequada.</sub>

Comment: Muito obrigado. Precisei alterar uma parte e adaptar no código, mas o seu conceito me ajudou muito e agora está funcionando.